# css changing for chrome but working perfect in firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I defined  custom css for my page it works perfect in firefox  but the lists are overlapping one another in chrome,I am not able get where I am wrong in the css

my css code is

```
    @media not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 


   #agile-row{
overflow-x:auto;
overflow-y:hidden;
align-items: flex-start;
display:flex;

}
#agile-board{
    margin-left:10px;

}
#i-box{
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    overflow-y:auto;

}
}
#agile-row{
overflow-x:auto;
overflow-y:hidden;
align-items: flex-start;
display:flex;

}
#agile-board{
    margin-left:10px;
}
#i-box{
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

[image: view in firefox]

[image: view in chrome]

my HTML code

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content  animated fadeInRight">
        <div class="row wrapper1 wrapper-content1">


                    <?php
                        foreach($taskStatusModel as $taskstatus ){
                    ?>
                        <div class="agile-board" style="display:inline-block">
                            <div class="ibox">
                                <div class="ibox-items" >
                                <div class="ibox-content">

                                <!--<div style="width:100%;text-align:right"><a href="index.php?r=pmt/project/project-kanban&id=<?=$model->id?>&delid=<?=$taskstatus->id?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" style="color:#fff;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></div>-->
                                    <input type="hidden" class="status" value="<?= $taskstatus->id ?>">
                                    <h3><?=$taskstatus->label?> 

                                    <a href="index.php?r=pmt/project/project-kanban&id=<?=$model->id?>&delid=<?=$taskstatus->id?>"  class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-circle pull-right"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </a>
                                    <a href="index.php?r=pmt/project/project-kanban&id=<?=$model->id?>&delid=<?=$taskstatus->id?>"  class="btn btn-xs btn-info btn-circle pull-right"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </a>

                                    </h3>
                                    <p class="small"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up"></i> Drag task between list</p>

                                    <div class="input-group">

                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onClick="opentaskpopup(this)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <?=Yii::t('app', 'New Task')?></a>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onClick="opendefectpopup(this)"><i class="fa fa-bug"></i> <?=Yii::t('app', 'New Defect')?></a>

                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="sortable-list connectList agile-list">

                                        <?php


                                        foreach(getTaskRecords($taskstatus->id) as $row){
                                        ?>
                                        <li class="warning-element">
                                            <input type="hidden" class="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>" a href="index.php?r=pmt/task/task-view&id=<?=$row['id']?>" >
                                            <input type="hidden" class="type" value="task">
                                          <a href="index.php?r=pmt/task/task-view&id=<?=$row['id']?>" style="word-wrap:break-word">  <?=$row['task_description']?></a>
                                            <div class="agile-detail">
                                                <a href="index.php?r=pmt/task/task-view&id=<?=$row['id']?>" class="pull-right btn btn-xs btn-warning"><?=$row['task_id']?></a>
                                                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?=date('d-m-Y',$row['added_at']);?>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <?php
                                            }
                                        ?>

                                    <!-- defect display begin-->

                                        <?php

                                        foreach(getDefectRecords($taskstatus->id) as $row){
                                        ?>
                                        <li class="danger-element">
                                            <input type="hidden" class="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>" a href="index.php?r=pmt/defect/defect-view&id=<?=$row['id']?>" >
                                            <input type="hidden" class="type" value="defect">
                                          <a href="index.php?r=pmt/defect/defect-view&id=<?=$row['id']?>" style="word-wrap:break-word">  <?=$row['defect_description']?></a>
                                            <div class="agile-detail">
                                                <a href="index.php?r=pmt/defect/defect-view&id=<?=$row['id']?>" class="pull-right btn btn-xs btn-danger"><?=$row['defect_id']?></a>
                                                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?=date('d-m-Y',$row['added_at']);?>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <?php
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </ul>
                                <!-- defect display end-->
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div><!-- needs action column ends -->
                        </div>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>


        </div> <!-- div row ends -->


    </div><!-- div wrapper ends -->
```

Every time a new list is added the row should automatically add it to the horizontally scrolling div

Comment: Why are you prefixing properties like `left`, `width, `height`, `overflow` with `-webkit-`??

Comment: just found in some answer that for chrome use `-webkit-` in front of each property @light

Comment: `-webkit-` is required for properties that are not (yet) official, but are implemented by webkit browsers (like Chrome). It is not meant to be spammed across every property. That's most likely the problem in your code.

Comment: Please post your HTML so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have added the HTML @KarimAG

Answer (score 0):

you should remove prefix from css

Comment: removed prefix but view still the same,I  updated the code and screenshot in the question